extending weak estimate
Let $T: L^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right) \cap {L^2}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right) \rightarrow L^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ be a linear operator which is of weak type $(1,1)$. Show that $T$ extends to a linear operator on $L^{1}\left(\mathbb{R}^{n}\right)$ which is of weak type $(1,1)$. While studying for hilbert transform this was seen. Can someone help me why this is true? Thank you.

I'd suggest elaborating more on your question and trying to make it more beneficial not just for you but for others as well.

This is essentially the same type of argument (in structure) as the usual BLT theorem from a normed space to a Banach space, except now we have to modify the argument by working with convergence in measure on the target space. I actually don’t know of references which explicitly write this out (many Fourier analysis books leave such density arguments to the reader).

Theorem.
Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu),(Y,\mathfrak{N},\nu)$ be measure spaces, let $p\in [1,\infty],q\in [1,\infty)$ and $E\subset L^p(\mu)$ a dense subspace. Let $T:E\to L^0(\nu)$ be a linear map which is of weak-type $(p,q)$ with constant $C$. Then, there is a unique linear extension $\widetilde{T}:L^p(\mu)\to L^0(\nu)$ of $T$, which is also of weak-type $(p,q)$. In fact, $\widetilde{T}$ can be bounded by the same constant $C$ as for $T$.

Here, $L^0(\nu)$ refers to the space of measurable (complex-valued) functions on $(Y,\mathfrak{N})$ modulo measure-zero identification relative to $\nu$. Also, I’ll write as short hand $\nu(\{\phi>\epsilon\})$ to mean $\nu(\{y\in Y\,:\, \phi(y)>\epsilon\})$.
Proof of Uniqueness. Let $f\in L^p(\mu)$ and pick any sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset E$ such that $f_n\to f$ in $L^p(\mu)$. Then, for any $\epsilon> 0$, we have
\begin{align}
\nu(\{|\widetilde{T}f-Tf_n|>\epsilon\})&=\nu\left(\{|\widetilde{T}f-\widetilde{T}f_n|>\epsilon\}\right)
\leq\left(\frac{C\|f-f_n\|_{L^p(\mu)}}{\epsilon}\right)^q,
\end{align}
where the first equality is because $\widetilde{T}$ is an extension of $T$, and the second is because $\widetilde{T}$ is weak-type $(p,q)$. As $n\to\infty$, the RHS vanishes by hypothesis, thereby proving that $Tf_n\to \widetilde{T}f$ in measure (relative to $\nu$). It is a standard fact that the limits in measure are unique, and so this proves that the operator $\widetilde{T}$ is completely determined by $T$, hence uniqueness.
Proof of Existence. Taking inspiration from the uniqueness proof and the usual BLT in Banach spaces, we essentially reverse the argument. Given any $f\in L^p(\mu)$, fix a sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset E$ such that $f_n\to f$ in $L^p(\mu)$. Observe that for any $\epsilon>0$ and $n,m\in\Bbb{N}$, $T$ being weak-type $(p,q)$ implies
\begin{align}
\nu(\{|Tf_n-Tf_m|>\epsilon\})&\leq \left(\frac{C\|f_n-f_m\|_{L^p(\mu)}}{\epsilon}\right)^q,
\end{align}
and so sending $n,m\to\infty$, the RHS approaches $0$ (because $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ converges (to $f$) and so is Cauchy in $L^p(\mu)$), thus showing that $\{Tf_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy in measure. Hence, there is an $F\in L^0(\nu)$ such that $Tf_n\to F$ in measure. This $F$ is our candidate for defining $\widetilde{T}f$, but of course we need to ensure well-definition.

Suppose $\{\phi_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset E$ is another sequence such that $\phi_n\to f$ in $L^p$. By the above argument, we know there is some $\Phi\in L^0(\nu)$ such that $T\phi_n\to \Phi$ in measure. We claim that $F=\Phi$. To see this, observe that for each $\epsilon>0$ and $n\in\Bbb{N}$, we have by the triangle inequality
\begin{align}
\nu(\{|F-\Phi|>3\epsilon\})&\leq \nu(\{|F-Tf_n|>\epsilon\})+
\nu(\{|Tf_n-T\phi_n|>\epsilon\})+ \nu(\{|T\phi_n-\Phi|>\epsilon\})\\
&\leq \nu(\{|F-Tf_n|>\epsilon\})+\left(\frac{C\|f_n-\phi_n\|_{L^p(\mu)}}{\epsilon}\right)^q+ \nu(\{|T\phi_n-\Phi|>\epsilon\}),
\end{align}
where for the middle term I used that $T$ is linear and weak-type $(p,q)$. As $n\to\infty$, the first and third terms vanish because of convergence in measure, while the second term vanishes because $f_n-\phi_n\to f-f=0$ in $L^p$. Hence, for each $\epsilon>0$, we have that $\nu(\{|F-\Phi|>\epsilon\})=0$, and so $F=\Phi$ in $L^0(\nu)$.

Therefore, we have a well-defined map $\widetilde{T}:L^p(\mu)\to L^0(\nu)$ such that for every $f\in L^p(\mu)$ and $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset E$ converging to $f$ in $L^p(\mu)$, we have that $Tf_n\to \widetilde{T}f$ in measure. We now need to check a bunch of properties about $\widetilde{T}$:

Extension: $\widetilde{T}$ is obviously an extension of $T$ (just take a constant sequence in $E$).
Linearity: $\widetilde{T}$ is linear by basic properties of convergence in measure: consider any $c\in\Bbb{C},f,g\in L^p(\mu)$ and take any approximating sequences $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty},\{g_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset E$. Then, $cT(f_n)+T(g_n)\to c\widetilde{T}(f)+\widetilde{T}(g)$ in measure. On the other hand, we have $cf_n+g_n\to cf+g$ in $L^p(\mu)$, and by linearity of $T$, we have $cT(f_n)+T(g_n)=T(cf_n+g_n)\to \widetilde{T}(cf+g)$ in measure. So, by uniqueness of limits in measure, we have $c\widetilde{T}(f)+\widetilde{T}(g)=\widetilde{T}(cf+g)$, proving linearity of $\widetilde{T}$.
Weak-type $(p,q)$: Let $f\in L^p(\mu)$ and consider any approximating sequence $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset E$. Then, for any $\lambda,\epsilon>0$ and $n\in\Bbb{N}$, we have by the triangle inequality and that $T$ is weak-type $(p,q)$,
\begin{align}
\nu(\{|\widetilde{T}f|>\lambda\})&\leq \nu(\{|\widetilde{T}f-Tf_n|>\epsilon\lambda\})+\nu(\{|Tf_n|>(1-\epsilon)\lambda\})\\
&\leq \nu(\{|\widetilde{T}f-Tf_n|>\epsilon\lambda\})+
\left(\frac{C\|f_n\|_{L^p(\mu)}}{(1-\epsilon)\lambda}\right)^q.
\end{align}
Now, take the limit $n\to\infty$; then the first term vanishes due to convergence in measure, and the second term we replace $\|f_n\|_{L^p(\mu)}$ with $\|f\|_{L^p(\mu)}$, because $f_n\to f$ in $L^p(\mu)$. Then, we can take the limit $\epsilon\to 0^+$ to finally deduce
\begin{align}
\nu(\{|\widetilde{T}f|>\lambda\})&\leq\left(\frac{C\|f\|_{L^p(\mu)}}{\lambda}\right)^q,
\end{align}
which proves that $\widetilde{T}$ is weak-type $(p,q)$, with the same bound $C$ as for $T$.

This completes the whole proof.

You can now apply this result to your special case on the real line. The only thing I’ll warn you about is that you actually cannot ensure the target space is $L^q(\nu)$, you can only ensure $L^0(\nu)$; and indeed, for the Hilbert transform, even if you start with a Schwartz function $f$, it is possible for $Hf$ to not be in $L^1(\Bbb{R})$ (in fact, for $f\in \mathcal{S}(\Bbb{R})$, we have that $Hf\in L^1(\Bbb{R})$ if and only if $\widehat{f}(0)=\int_{\Bbb{R}}f=0$).
